# Web-app security: substitution of JavaScript code and data

Tags: javascript, security, web-applications

Now I'm thinking of implementing eval()-ing of some code, dynamically loaded from server. Any kind of "eval()"ing is not a good idea, actually (especially for security). What comes to mind:

If i do not use SSL or any server-authentication technique it's so easy to substitute my packages and run any JS code on users machine. Now, when there's some API for hardware (WebGL) it might (?) be dangerous.

But, on the other and, it makes no sense if I secure that somehow, because if user serfs the net JS code might be simply substituted when browser requests for .js file from server loading the page (from another web-site for example).

So, if I have no important data in my web-app - should I implement any king of server-authentication?

Comment: And why do you need to eval this?

Comment: Where does the JS come from, do you write it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the page containing the `eval()` instruction and the JS source code you are loading dynamically are on the same server, there is probably no decreased security because of this - an attacker could simply replace the *page* instead of the dynamically loaded code, and achieve the same destructive effect, whether you use `eval()` or not.

`eval()` ing dynamically loaded code is done all the time in Javascript. For example, when you load HTML through jQuery's `.load()`, any JS in it will be extracted and `eval()`ed automatically.

If you need to `eval()` something this way, I don't think you add a *security* problem (although you may very well be able to avoid using it by changing your architecture.)

Comment: a MitM could actually inject code into the webpage, you should IMHO at least mention that.

Comment: @Niklas I *am* mentioning that - `an attacker could simply replace the page instead of the dynamically loaded code` is it not clear enough? Suggestions for improvement are welcome. My point is that if there's a man in the middle, you're screwed anyway - but whether you eval dynamically loaded JS code or not, doesn't make the situation worse

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark - If a man in the middle attack could replace the javascript that was dynamically loaded, then they could also just have changed the host web page too.  So, Pekka's point was that there's no new vulnerability here.  If the MitM can intercept and change browser requests, the main web page is just as vulnerable to tampering.  Using SSL will increase the security against both types of tampering - requiring that the attacker to compromise the SSL request (not so easy) before being able to tamper.

Comment: @jfriend00: this depends on whether the dynamically loaded javascript comes from the same or another server.

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark - and as Pekka's answer says "on the same server" - that's the context here for my comments.

Comment: @jfriend00: Must have missed that. Never mind. I am not sure whether this is the actual situation that OP wanted to know about, though. We can't be sure, so maybe something should be said about the situation where the dynamically `eval`'d JS comes from a different server?

Answer (score 0):

You are being extra paranoid regarding usage of eval. If someone can modify your server's response which gets eval'ed, they can introduce a new eval as well.

If your concern is only about modification in your responses via Man-In-Middle attack, you should use SSL no matter whether you are eval'ing or not.